# http 304 response combined with cache-control does not seem to work with max-age

Tags: http

On Chrome the cache-control header works when combined with a 304 response.
I have checked this with "cache-control no-store" which makes the Chrome make a regular GET request to the server next time it needs that resource; as expected.

However, "cache-control max-age=42" doesn't work as expected. Instead of not making a GET request to the server the next 42 seconds it makes GET requests with an if-modified-since header even though it shouldn't do that before the 42 seconds has passed.

It's weird that a 200-response with "cache-control max-age=42" work as expected, but a 304-response doesn't.

Any explanation and maybe a way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only tested this with Chrome.

When Chrome makes a GET request with an if-modified-since header any max-age in the 304-response is interpreted as a max-age from when the resource was originally returned instead of a max-age from the time of the 304-response.
So in order to make this work the new max-age should be (time-since-original-response + max-age-you-want).

However, the upper limit of max-age is one year.